# How to get posts of a specific user with Instagram API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, instagram-api

I would like to have the recent posts of an specific user, like Banksy.
I came up with the following, but it will give me an error of:

```
GET https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/banksy/media/recent/?access_token={token}&callback=jQuery11110924438442569226_1445956181244&_=1445956181245
```

My ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/banksy/media/recent/?access_token={token}",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('jfsdahuifhasudh')
                console.log(response);
                // placing the images on the page
                // for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    
                    var html = '<a href="' + response.data[i].link + '" >'+
                    '<img src="' + response.data[i].images.low_resolution.url + '" alt="thumbnail" /></a>';
                    $(".instafeed").html(html);

                // }
            }, 

            error: function(data) {
                console.log('We have a problem!');
            }
        });
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: This one: GET https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/banksy/media/recent/?access_token=225356…1f641437&callback=jQuery11110924438442569226_1445956181244&_=1445956181245

Comment: What about it? @Caspert, I believe you're not able to parse the `JSON` correctly, right?

Comment: The url is returning a 404 meaning the resource is not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the username in your query; `banksy` in your case. [Resolve the `username` into ID](http://jelled.com/instagram/lookup-user-id) then use the `id` in your query. For example;

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/45951573/media/recent/?access_token={token}

*The API will return posts **only** if the account is public.

#### Edit

To get posts tagged with a specific hashtag use:

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token={token}

[Further reading: Instagram API; Tags](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/)

#### Update

instaJS is a jQuery plugin I wrote in past. What makes this plugin unique is that it accepts `username` instead of forcing users to resolve their `id`. Completely Free to use :), and of course contribution is always welcomed [InstaJS on Github](https://github.com/adamazad/instajs/)

Comment: The account of Banksy is public, do you need then also a username ID?

Comment: *"*The API will return posts only if the account is public."* is just a notice, not directly related to your problem. :) Try the example.

Comment: Thanks to this answer, I updated your code a little: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/gd677jdp/

Comment: Thank you. But is there also a way to get only posts of some specific hashtag?

Comment: Thanks for the nice example. :) @lharby

Comment: Thank you lharby and Adam Azad. Only one more thing, should you have an user-id to get posts from it. Because when I visit for example: www.instagram.com/banksy it will give me directly the page with posts of Banksy..

Comment: @Caspert, the API requires an `id`, but I have written a jQuery plugin that has a function resolves the username into `id`. Then, it uses `id` to get posts

Comment: How is your plugin called?

Comment: @Caspert, check the updated answer with link to the repo.